# How to find the root cause of ORA-54033 error when altering column data type

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am attempting to alter the data type of a column from a NUMBER to a VARCHAR2 in an existing database table. When running the following ALTER TABLE statement I receive the "ORA-54033: column to be modified is used in a virtual column expression" error:

```
ALTER TABLE table MODIFY (col1 varchar2(8));
```

I have already worked through the directions listed [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/ora-54033-and-the-hidden-virtual-column-mystery). When looking at the SYS generated export statistics using the following query

```
select column_name, data_default, hidden_column 
from   user_tab_cols
where  table_name = 'Table';
```

there is nothing referencing col1 in export statistics. There are about 15 hidden, SYS generated rows associated with the table and they all have a data default value of <Long>. There are no virtual columns in the DDL, nor is this column being used for any indexes or as a FK. I have also had the DBA run the following:

```
SELECT EXTENSION_NAME, EXTENSION, CREATOR, DROPPABLE
FROM DBA_STAT_EXTENSIONS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='Table'
```

and the output lines up with what I find in user_tab_cols. Where else can I look for this seemingly buried virtual column?

Comment: Did you actually drop the extended statistics? `<Long>` is likely a placeholder for a value too long to be displayed (i.e. a "LONG" datatype).

Comment: I'm guessing you have a function-based index (perhaps several) which uses that column. Oracle implements function-based indexes by creating a hidden column to store the value of the index expression, then bases the index on the hidden column. Dropping the function-based index which includes `COL1` may let you proceed.